# I am getting following Makefile error, any helpful suggestions are appreciated

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, systypes.h

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong in my make file? Any help in correct direction is appreciated.
Error:

```
make: ../apue.3e/systype.sh: Command not found
Makefile:3: ../apue.3e/Make.defines.: No such file or directory
Makefile:15: ../apue.3e/Make.libapue.inc: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `../apue.3e/Make.libapue.inc'.  Stop.
```

My Makefile looks like this currently:

```
    ROOT=../apue.3e
PLATFORM=$(shell $(ROOT)/systype.sh)
include $(ROOT)/Make.defines.$(PLATFORM)

PROGS = shell2

all:    $(PROGS)

%:  %.c $(LIBAPUE)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.c -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS) $(TEMPFILES) *.o

include $(ROOT)/Make.libapue.inc
```

My directories structure looks like this,I think my ROOT path is not correct but I cant figure out :

```
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 ~]$ pwd
/export/homes/singhrav
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 ~]$ ls
a.out                 cse_grid_tutorial   Makefile             OOP            server              tmp
client                Homework03SinghRav  Millionproject1      output         shell2.c            typescript
csci3800hw-singh.txt  hw2                 mysearch-result.txt  output2        SinghRavisher_04
csci3800sp22          lab1                myShell              pythonProject  SinghRavisher_HW02
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 ~]$ cd csci3800sp22
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 ~/csci3800sp22]$ ls
apue.3e  src.3e.tar.gz
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 ~/csci3800sp22]$ cd apue.3e
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 apue.3e]$ ls
cadvio       environ    include  Make.defines.freebsd  Make.libapue.inc  relation   systype.sh
daemons     exercises  intro    Make.defines.linux    printer           signals    termios
datafiles   figlinks   ipc1     Make.defines.macos    proc              sockets    threadctl
db          filedir    ipc2     Make.defines.solaris  pty               standards  threads
DISCLAIMER  fileio     lib      Makefile              README            stdio
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 apue.3e]$ cd intro
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 intro]$ ls
getcputc    hello    ls1    Makefile  mycat.c  shell1.c  shell2.c   testerror.c  uidgid.c
getcputc.c  hello.c  ls1.c  mycat     shell1   shell2    testerror  uidgid
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 intro]$ cp /export/homes/singhrav/csci3800sp22/apue.3e/intro/shell2 /export/homes/singhrav/lab1
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 intro]$ cd ..
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 apue.3e]$ cd ..
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 ~/csci3800sp22]$ ls
apue.3e  src.3e.tar.gz
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 ~/csci3800sp22]$ cd ..
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 ~]$ ls
a.out                 cse_grid_tutorial   Makefile             OOP            server              tmp
client                Homework03SinghRav  Millionproject1      output         shell2.c            typescript
csci3800hw-singh.txt  hw2                 mysearch-result.txt  output2        SinghRavisher_04
csci3800sp22          lab1                myShell              pythonProject  SinghRavisher_HW02
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 ~]$ cd lab1
[singhrav@csci-gnode-02 ~/lab1]$ ls
Makefile  shell2
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths in a makefile are interpreted relative to the current working directory, not relative to the location of the makefile in which they appear.

Given the directory structure and makefile content you show, therefore, that makefile will only work if you launch `make` from directory `csci3800sp22/apue.3e`, which makes the whole `ROOT` business more or less moot.  You have not provided enough information about how and from where you are launching `make` to support a recommendation of what you should do instead.

Comment: I think you are right, I knew my path was problem, it worked now i think.